# Automatically subscribing a user to sync document libraries

Tags: document-library, site-collection, sync, offline-sync

I have a site collection with multiple sub-sites, each with their own document libraries. Once the project is fully under way, there will likely be a couple of hundred document libraries in the system.

I need a way to allow new users to access all of these libraries through a sync-like feature. Some users will require to be 'fully synched' to the system, where they can access the files offline, but other will just need to see and have access to the file system, preferably through windows explorer for easy file upload and familiarity.

Obviously I can't manually go to each library and click the 'Sync' button 100+ times for every new user to the system, so is there a way to automatically subscribe users to sync all documents libraries within a site collection? I've tried looking at mapping Sharepoint to a network drive, but the solutions I've found also suggest adding individual libraries manually instead of adding the whole site. This also need to stay up to date when new subsites and document libraries are created, so that all users are automatically 'synched' to the new libraries.

Comment: hi @mark-e, did you manage to find any solutions for this task?

Answer (score 0):

If mapping to a drive letter would work for you rather than syncing, and you would consider a third party tool, you could take a look at Zee Drive. [Zee Drive is a tool for mapping SharePoint Online team sites, document libraries and OneDrive for Business to network drives](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/).

Zee Drive has a central mapped drive configuration; as the administrator you define the mapped drives and publish them out to all users on your subscription.

Disclosure: I work for the company that develops Zee Drive.

Answer (score 0):

The new OneDrive sync can now [Auto Mount Team Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-group-policy#AutoMountTeamSites) using InTune policies. There are a [large number of settings](https://practical365.com/intune-policies-for-a-user-friendly-onedrive-for-business-client-deployment/) you will want to configure. Knowing Microsoft, this is all subject to change so it's best to seek source material for how to do this in your specific tenant.

[An example found here](https://letsconfigmgr.com/mem-automatic-syncing-of-onedrive-shared-libs-via-intune/) is a multi-page document so I don't want to copy it wholesale here.