# Force all users in a company to sync a single SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, onedrive

If we want to sync a single SharePoint document library we should navigate to it in the browser and click `Sync` button. Then, in a sync tool dialog box that pops-up in Windows, we perform a few actions including entering your email, if you never did it before.

Now is there a way to do it automatically for every user in the company using some automation?

I would be very grateful for any suggestions. Including 3rd party tools. I'm pretty sure there are quite a few companies who would like to know the answer to this question.

There is a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213758/automatically-subscribing-a-user-to-sync-document-libraries), but it's not exactly the same and it has no replies yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few options:

1. If there are limited numbers of users you can map a SharePoint library as a network drive. More information [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2616712/how-to-configure-and-to-troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives-that-connect-to-sharepoint-online-sites-in-office-365) and [here](https://nikpatel.net/2014/12/23/mapping-network-drive-for-office-365-and-sharepoint-online/).
2. Create a login script to automatically map your OneDrive for Business upon login, script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/OneDriveMapper-automaticall-d7d498b0).
3. You can also consider a 3rd party tool. My company uses [Cloud Drive Mapper](https://www.iamcloud.com/cloud-drive-mapper/) to map all the OneDrives as a network drive.